# Can not access public method in extended DB class

Tags: php, oop

I have a DB class. All other classes uses this as extender. But when I want to run query method from inside of extended class method it throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/logics/Classes/Class.DB.php:623
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/logics/Classes/Class.DB.php(483): SafeMySQL->error('SafeMySQL: . Fu...')
#1 /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/logics/Classes/Class.DB.php(233): SafeMySQL->rawQuery('SELECT userpass...')
#2 /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/logics/Classes/Class.Users.php(114): SafeMySQL->getRow('SELECT userpass...', 'h.elvin@ya.ru')
#3 /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/logics/Classes/Class.Users.php(90): User->verify_password()
#4 /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/index.php(26): User->login(Array)
#5 /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/logics/Router/Router.php(70): {closure}(Object(Request))
#6 /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/logics/Router/Router.php(75): Router->resolve()
#7 [internal function]: Router->__destruct()
#8 {main}
  thrown in /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/logics/Classes/Class.DB.php on line 623
```

I use this DB class: https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql

And my User class is as follow:

```
    class User extends SafeMySQL {

    private $useremail;

        // Login
        public function login($creds = array()) {

            if (is_array($creds) && !empty($creds)) {

                $this->useremail = trim($creds['useremail']);
                $this->userpassword = trim($creds['userpassword']);

                if ($this->verify_password()) {

                    session_regenerate_id(true);
                    $_SESSION['id'] = session_id();
                    $_SESSION['useremail'] = $this->useremail;
                    $_SESSION['is_logged'] = true;
                    $this->is_logged = true;

                    // Set a cookie that expires in one week
                    if (isset($_POST['remember']))
                        setcookie('useremail', $this->useremail, time() + 604800);

                    // To avoid resending the form on refreshing
                    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                    exit();

                } else $this->error[] = 'Wrong user or password.';

            }

        }

        // Check if password match
        private function verify_password() {
            $get_pass = $this->getRow('SELECT userpassword FROM Users WHERE useremail=?s', $this->useremail);
            return password_verify($this->password, $get_pass[0]['userpassword']);

        }
}
```

The error message above appears when code is been executed at `verify_password` method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm totally note sure if this will solve your problem, but....

The `rawQuery()` method in your DB class seems to have a bad check in it. On line 474 it says:

```
if (!$res)
```

where `$res` contains the result of `mysqli_query()`. In the manual it says about this result:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
> EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
> other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

So I think the check should be:

```
if ($res === FALSE)
```

as used in some of the comments in the manual.

Comment: If it can only return an object or true/false, then testing `!res` is the same as testing `$res === false`? But apparently it got accepted as an answer so I guess it helped somehow :)

Comment: @KIKO Yes! Now everything works fine! Sorry, as I am new in development and trying not to bother with basic questions. But anyway thank you so much!

Comment: @Jeto That's a valid comment. But what does `mysqli_query()` return in case a SELECT returns no results? It could be NULL, and then there is a difference. Anyway, it is always better to do the best check you can, and in this case you only what to see if the result is FALSE.

Comment: Now I have another issue with this DB class. When I am trying to execute query on line 466 it says that `$this->conn` is Null. But constructor seems return connection without problem.

Comment: @ElvinHuseynov If this problem is unrelated to your original question, which you seem to imply, then you should ask a new question. I do wonder about the quality of that DB class though.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Ok. Got it)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware If the result is empty then it will still return an object with 0 row unless the doc is wrong. You're definitely right that testing with `=== false` is better/safer in 99% cases, I'm just pointing out that it shouldn't make any difference in this specific case. Not sure how it did.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a bug in the library you're using, right here:
https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php#L623

There should be parentheses around `new $this` (which btw I didn't even know worked, I believe `new self` / `new static` would be cleaner, but not the point).

Anyway, to solve your issue, when you instantiate your `User` instance, try doing it like this :

`$user = new User(['errmode' => 'error']);`

This should trigger an error instead of throwing an exception, and let you see the actual error in your query (because there seems to be one).

Otherwise, you can fix the error from that lib yourself (add the parentheses) and/or create a github issue to notify its creator.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much for your review!